# ssl encryption in rsyslog

Tags: encryption, ssl, rsyslog

could anyone give me hint where this problem is,

I am unable to encrypt log files comming from my client machine to central log, i dont understand the reason, could i get any relevent information. (i can see unencrypted files, coming towards central server (ngrep - in and out both))

Senario, I am using, already created certificate which is an authorized CA by godaddy.

Client rsyslog.conf:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock.so
$ModLoad imklog.so
$ModLoad imtcp


$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /rsyslog/pki/something.example.net.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /rsyslog/pki/something.example.com.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /rsyslog/pki/something.example.com.key

$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name 
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 

*.* @@machine.example.net:10514
```

unusual: system gets hung, when i enable defaultnetstreamDriver gtls

Server rsyslog.conf

```
$ModLoad ommysql
#$UDPServerRUn 514

$ModLoad immark # provides --MARK-- message capability
#$ModLoad imudp # provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp # provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imgssapi # provides GSSAPI syslog reception
#$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)


$InputTCPServerRun 10514

*.*    :ommysql:127.0.0.1,dbname,username,password

$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /var/www/html/rsyslog/ssl/something.example.net.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /var/www/html/rsyslog/ssl/something.example.net.crt
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /var/www/html/rsyslog/ssl/something.example.net.key 


$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode  anon
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *.example.net
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
```

Comment: Actually, got the issue, if anyone faces the same problem, there is nothing wrong in code however, the version of rsyslog is not supported by encryption, required, is 5.8.4 however, i havent tested any other previous version to ensure if other works or not. for sure 5.8.4 works.

Answer (score 2):

People, may be having same issue, so i would like to share if anyone ends up here..

Actually, got the issue, if anyone faces the same problem, there is nothing wrong in code however, the version of rsyslog is not supported by encryption, required, is 5.8.4 however, i havent tested any other previous version to ensure if other works or not. for sure 5.8.4 works